# Eureka client not able to register with eureka server when deployed on external tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Tried to deploy spring boot eureka server as war on external tomcat and tried to register eureka client to server but getting registration status 404. Hope someone might be success with this approach. Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like it's because of the context path `tomcat` gives to your `eureka` server app. are you sure you deploy your war file on context root of `tomcat`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Able to deploy eureka server as Root context and register my zuul and another app as well. Now I am facing new problem, when i try to hit any rest service via zuul, i am getting connection refused error.

Comment: seems like you can't send request to your `Zull` server. what is the response of {zuul-host}/health ?